# Android Firebase phone Authentication

Tags: android

I am using firebase phone authentication in my app. It works in the run-time apk. But when I generate a signed apk for realese purpose, the phone authentication doesn't work. It says the app validation failed (cf. the image below).

[image]

Comment: have you added project SHA key to Firebase project properly ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed to add SHA-1 of Release APK in your firebase project.

In order to get SHA-1 of Release APK,

```
keytool -list -v -keystore {keystore_name} -alias {alias_name}
```

For example,

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /Users/example/Desktop/example.jks -alias example
```

After you got fingerprint, just enter it in the firebase console like you did before using fingerprint for debug.